# Issue with the Media Encoder Service in PKS for SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, development

It may not be directly related to SharePoint but wounder if someone could help me. 
I have configured a PKS on a new sharePoint 2007 environment however facing the below issue with the media encoder service. Not sure what could be the issue, please help me if you have any idea on this.

```
[5/23/2011 5:48:08 PM] Adding 'C:\UploadFolder\0a0c3480-9f9c-4543-8cc6-d5f01a2d14c5\155cb14e-08e4-4b33-b361-69d855d63e07\11\Ringtone 01.wma' to transcoding queue
[5/23/2011 5:48:08 PM] Adding 'C:\UploadFolder\0a0c3480-9f9c-4543-8cc6-d5f01a2d14c5\155cb14e-08e4-4b33-b361-69d855d63e07\11\Ringtone 01.wma' to transcoding queue
[5/23/2011 5:48:11 PM] Found new item: 'C:\UploadFolder\0a0c3480-9f9c-4543-8cc6-d5f01a2d14c5\155cb14e-08e4-4b33-b361-69d855d63e07\11\Ringtone 01.wma'. 1 items remaining.
[5/23/2011 5:48:11 PM] GetListItem entered
[5/23/2011 5:48:11 PM] Error[fileSystemWatcher_Created]: There is an error in XML document (6, 1078).
StackTrace:
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at MediaEncoderService.Lists.Lists.GetListItems(String listName, String viewName, XmlNode query, XmlNode viewFields, String rowLimit, XmlNode queryOptions, String webID)
   at MediaEncoderService.ListWebService.GetListItem(String itemId, String listName)
   at MediaEncoderService.PKSListItem..ctor(String path, MEConfig meConfig, Recode Recoder)
   at MediaEncoderService.MediaEncoderService.ActOnNewFile(String fullPath)

[5/23/2011 5:48:11 PM] Found new item: 'C:\UploadFolder\0a0c3480-9f9c-4543-8cc6-d5f01a2d14c5\155cb14e-08e4-4b33-b361-69d855d63e07\11\Ringtone 01.wma'. 0 items remaining.
[5/23/2011 5:48:11 PM] GetListItem entered
[5/23/2011 5:48:11 PM] Error[fileSystemWatcher_Created]: There is an error in XML document (6, 1078).
StackTrace:
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at MediaEncoderService.Lists.Lists.GetListItems(String listName, String viewName, XmlNode query, XmlNode viewFields, String rowLimit, XmlNode queryOptions, String webID)
   at MediaEncoderService.ListWebService.GetListItem(String itemId, String listName)
   at MediaEncoderService.PKSListItem..ctor(String path, MEConfig meConfig, Recode Recoder)
   at MediaEncoderService.MediaEncoderService.ActOnNewFile(String fullPath)
```

Comment: Looks like the error is in some XML document? I'm not sure if your question belongs on SharePoint.SE but it looks like the codeplex site has been abandoned as well so I'll leave this open for a bit.

Comment: finally, i found that it is an issue with the view fields  in the method GetListItem in the class PKSListItem  ,NFS xml blob field causes the issue, Media Encoder works if the field removed from the view fields however it is an important field used in other places. Is there a way to fix this issue without skipping the field from the view fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted and recreate the "NFS xml blob" field, it resolves the issue.

Comment: @Team, Please feel free to close or cancel this question.

Comment: Mark it as answer